# NoClassDefFound error when running roboelectric test

Tags: java, android, eclipse, robolectric

I am trying to run a simple roboelectric test by following this [Guide](http://robolectric.org/eclipse-quick-start/). When i try to run the test, i get the error given below.

> java.lang.NoCassDefFoundError: com/google/android/collect/maps

**Please see the complete error trace below.**

[image]

**Also check my project structure**

[image]

**I am using the following**

1. Eclipse Juno (With ADT Bundle)
2. Compile SDK - API 18, Target SDK - API 18
3. Roboelectric 2.4

Comment: have you included google maps apis ? or ur sdk has that ? seems class is not found

Comment: my sample application does not use google maps. Even in guide, they have not mentioned to add maps.jar

Comment: yet i tried adding maps.jar to the test project. (Not there in screenshot) Still the error didnt went away

Comment: You open sdk, under extras u ll get google maps api, i guess u ll hv to update ur sdk. Did you try that..?

Comment: @Nielarshi i finally figured out that its looking for collection map, and not google maps

Comment: Did you add dependency of you android project to java project?